# I need the id of the input textbox that is calling a function onKeyDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I need is to get the id of an HTML textbox that is calling a function onkeydown. The problem is that the textbox is being added to the page dynamically. So I need some simple Java Script code to handle this for me inside the function it is calling.

Let me know if this needs clarifying.

Here's my function:

```
function DigitsOnly() {
    var KeyID = event.keyCode;
    if ((KeyID > 47 && KeyID < 58) || (KeyID > 95 && KeyID < 106)) {
    } else {
        alert("Digits only, please.");
        alert(this.id);
    }
}
```

and below is a function that adds a bunch of HTML to a form dynamically. One of the HTML thingies is a input textbox that calls the DigitsOnly() function. Note: Whenever the client pressed the Add Another button, these HTML input boxes and dropdownlists, etc. get loaded into the page with an incremented id attached to them so as to not all have the same id. I decided to add a class to the input box that calls the DigitsOnly function that increments as well. So what I need to do, again, is (inside the DigitsOnly function) to find out the exact id that is calling the function so that I can specify which textbox to remove the unwanted character from... Hope this makes sense..

Comment: I am using JQuery, yes. What shall I do to make this thing work? I posted my function in a comment back to another fellow here if you needed to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, everyone. So I didn't seem to see any working results with your examples. Thanks for your input nonetheless. Anyway, I spoke with my little brother Timothy today and he explained what I needed to do. Here is the working code:

< input type="text" onkeydown="DisplayInputInfo(this)" id="myTextbox" name="textboxName" />

```
function DisplayInputInfo(theTextbox) {

alert(theTextbox.name);    
    alert(theTextbox.id);
}
```

As you can see, the 'this' keyword is passed as argument to the function we want to call 
example: DisplayInputInfo(this);
   For this demo, I tied the function to the 'onkeydown' event. THEN, in the function itself, a scope name is placed into the parentheses, and it is that name that is used to represent the input textbox (or whatever element desired).

So, for my purpose, I needed to do more than simply alert the name and id of my textbox. Actually, my textboxes were added to my form upon button click. So each new dynamically added textbox was given a name plus an incremented digit that their names wouldn't all be the same. (this is why I didn't know in advance the exact name of my textbox) Nonetheless, the functionality above enabled me to use the individual textboxes as they were added to the form, when the 'onkeydown' event was invoked.

I was able to capture the keystrokes typed, alert when it was not a digit as needed, and remove the unwanted character.

Such a simple solution. But soooo awesome nonetheless! :D

Thanks again, guys, for your quick response!!

Answer (score 2):

Attach the `onkeydown` event after the element is added to the page

then reference the element's id inside the function with..

```
this.id
```

so...

```
// after textbox is added to page...

textElement.onkeydown = function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<script>
DigitsOnly = function(e) { 
    var KeyID = e.keyCode;
    if ((KeyID > 47 && KeyID < 58) || (KeyID > 95 && KeyID < 106)) 
        return console.log(e); 
    else {
        alert(this.id);
        alert('Digits only please');
        setTimeout("checkStr()", 500); 
        return false; 
    }
};

document.getElementById('myInput').onkeypress = DigitsOnly;
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. This is being alerted as 'undefined'

Comment: Here's my function: function DigitsOnly() {

     var KeyID = event.keyCode;
     if ((KeyID > 47 && KeyID < 58) || (KeyID > 95 && KeyID < 106)) {
     }
     
     else {
         alert("Digits only, please.");
         alert(this.id);
         setTimeout("checkStr()", 500);
     }

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... In my sloppy looking function above I have, among other things, an alert with this.id inside. The alert comes back as 'undefined'...So what do you want me to do then?

Comment: @ cvsguimaraes I removed my function and replaced it with yours and the javascript wouldn't execute. Not sure if I should have written it differently. I'll go ahead and show my code again.

Comment: @James Khouri DevJunkie I'v just missed a semicolon, my bad srry